# Make an application for youtube live broadcast

Tags: ios

I want to make an  app which show live streaming on Youtube. where can I start?. Any Api or any tutorial available for that.

Appriciate for help

Comment: may be this link help you https://github.com/youtube/yt-direct-lite-iOS

Comment: @VinodJadhav you want to show this video on web view.. or anything else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Test **YouTube Live Streaming API**. 
here is documentation available for that https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/getting-started